# English equivalent for the german term "Bestellrunde"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

The German term "Bestellrunde" literally translates as "order round/turn" or "a round/turn of orders".

It implies a request to consumers/customers to place their order within a given period of time to take part in (what I would call) a bulk order, often orchestrated by a single person or entity.
This may happen multiple times (thus the connotation of rounds/turns) but always in a discrete fashion.

As an example: Think of a group of women at a Tupperware party. The Tupperware "consultant" takes each guest's order that night (the first "Bestellrunde"). Weeks later the "consultant" would contact that night's guests by phone, offering them a chance to place another order (the second "Bestellrunde").

Comment: You could use 'the first batch/set of orders'. A 'round' has a similar meaning, but is usually used with a restricted subset of prepositional phrases (a round of drinks / endless round of activities / daily round of housework and shopping ...) and in other fixed phrases (a round of applause ...).

Comment: Assuming it's not just a "repeat order", I don't think the concept itself has sufficient currency in Anglophone countries to merit a specific noun.